# In EmberJS, how do I maintain child component state through collection updates?

Tags: ember.js

Quite simply, is there a best practice for persisting child component state through collection updates. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate:

1.13
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jazerepuqe/1/edit?html,js,output

2.4.4
https://ember-twiddle.com/6275ccd28b75c5f24d22c697049f291d?openFiles=components.parent-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.child-component.hbs

How can I toggle item heights, add a new item, and have the existing children maintain their states? Do I need to write custom view-model management code? Is this something solved in newer versions of Ember?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that every time you add an item you return a new array with a static heightToggle property of false. How about you change the structure of baseItems and newItems to actually have the property of heightToggle.

```
          baseItems: Ember.A([
            Ember.Object.create({text: 'red', heightToggled: true}),
            Ember.Object.create({text: 'blue', heightToggled: true}),
            Ember.Object.create({text: 'green', heightToggled: true}),
          ]),
          items: Ember.computed.map('baseItems', function(item) { 
             return Ember.Object.create({
               text: item.text,
               heightToggled: item.heightToggled 
             })
          }),

          actions: {
            click() {
              this.get('items').forEach(childItem => {
                childItem.toggleProperty('heightToggled');      
              });
            },
            addItem() {
              this.get('baseItems').pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
                text: 'yellow' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000), // Random identifier
                heightToggled: Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))}) // Random booleans
              );
            }
          }
    });
```